# How to deal with not getting updates on a task from colleagues?

Tags: communication, people-management, conflict-resolution

I often deal with colleagues (who are not in working in the same place), who promise to deal with some task (they have to fix something, install something, etc), but the promised deadline comes and goes, and I do not hear back.

Example:

> **Tuesday:** "I will fix this issue and deploy a new version by the end of the day."
>   **Wednesday 9am:** No new version deployed (and an important work I need to work on is blocked).

When and how should I ask for an update? How long to wait? In what time intervals to ask? When to talk to my boss that I am blocked (and I do not want to do that twice each day)?

In the example, should I ask right in the morning? Every hour? What is the right way to deal with that?

Answer (score 7):

You simply ask them.

> Was there an issue in deploying the new version yesterday?  When can I expect this to be released as it's currently blocking one of my tasks.

If you don't get an answer to that email by the end of the recipient's working day, then you should report to your manager that you have a block on one of your tasks and let them deal with it.

How often/quickly you chase up is obviously dependent on the urgency.

Answer (score 1):

Direct communication is probably best. Things slip all the time, higher priority items bump lower priority items and what you wanted to get done doesn't. Through no ill intent of the ones involved.

Bearing that in mind, it's best to directly check with the person and ping them a day or so after it's due to see what the status is.
Better yet, if this is something important to you, you need to be a bit more involved in it getting done. You can't treat it as *fire and forget* if it not getting done will result in big problems on your side!

Escalations to their manager is usually a bad thing - only do it for really serious issues!